# MongoDB: How to return only the last element of a list?

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to only return the last element of a list stored in a Mongo object?  My list is pretty long and I am only interested in the last element stored in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [$slice](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) operator with negative count to return only last items from array query returns. `-1` will bring you only last one item:

```
 db.collection.find( {}, { array: { $slice: -1 } } )
```